# NameError: name 'sosete' is not defined

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I try to get the len of all products displayed on this site https://www.bershka.com/ro/femeie/accesorii/%C8%99osete-c1010194004.html

Using this code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


options = Options()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
driver.get("https://www.bershka.com/ro/femeie/accesorii/%C8%99osete-c1010194004.html")


cookies_bttn = driver.find_element(By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
cookies_bttn.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
country_save = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#geoblocking > div > div > div.select-country-container > button.button.is-sm.confirm")
country_save.click()
hoover = ActionChains(driver)

product = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "grid-item normal")
z = 0
for sosete in product:
    sth = sosete.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content"]/div/div/div[2]/section[1]/div/ul/li["+str(z+1)+"]/div')
    z = z+1
    print(len(sth))
```

I don't know why it is saying sosete is not defined while I clearly defined it in for loop. Any help please?

Also if I try to get all products len by using class name only 20 products out of 31 are printed like so:

```
whole_product = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "grid-card-link")
print(len(whole_product))


i = 0
product = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-image")
hoover.move_to_element(product)
sosete = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "quick-purchase")
for purchase_bttn in sosete:
    purchase_bttn.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Could you provide the traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\PythonPortofolio\test5cheatsheet.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(len(sosete))
              ^^^^^^
NameError: name 'sosete' is not defined

Comment: try printing inside for loop

Comment: There could be a possibility that `product` is empty, so it doesn't get iterated therefore `sosete` is not defined

Comment: Akshay tried printing inside loop and it just Process finished with exit code 0 without printing anything

Comment: @Pto I tried printing the product and it printed 0. So I got the first child element and it prints 20. However on the site there are 31 products displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page is being loaded dynamically, as you scroll. here is way to (correctly) define the product range, scroll the page, wait for them to load, and print them out:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
url = 'https://www.bershka.com/ro/femeie/accesorii/%C8%99osete-c1010194004.html'
driver.get(url)
footer = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="footer-social"]')))
pbody = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
for x in range(5):
    pbody.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    print('scrolled')
    t.sleep(5)
sosetute = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="category-product-card"]')))

print('How many socks?', len(sosetute))
for ciorapel in sosetute:
    print(ciorapel.text)
```

Result in terminal:

```
scrolled
scrolled
scrolled
scrolled
scrolled
How many socks? 31
Set 3 perechi de șosete fluture
55,90 RON
Șosete lungi cu dungi
39,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete ciuperci
39,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete Snoopy
39,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete Fetițele Powerpuff
55,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete Lizzie
39,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete până la gleznă broderie
39,90 RON
Jambiere denim
109,90 RON
Jambiere blană
129,90 RON
Jambiere tricot
55,90 RON
+ 1 Culoare
Jambiere tricot
55,90 RON
+ 1 Culoare
Set 3 perechi șosete print
39,90 RON
Set 4 perechi șosete neon
39,90 RON
Set 4 perechi șosete simple
39,90 RON
Set de 3 perechi de șosete cu text
39,90 RON
Set de 2 perechi de șosete texturate
55,90 RON
Șosete print Art Series
69,90 RON
+ 1 Culoare
Șosete print Art Series
69,90 RON
+ 1 Culoare
Set 3 perechi șosete print
39,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete curly broderie
39,90 RON
Set de 3 perechi de șosete racing
39,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete print
39,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete print
39,90 RON
Set de 3 perechi de șosete racing
39,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete cu imprimeu varsity
39,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete lungi varsity campus
39,90 RON
Șosete text
39,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete colorate
39,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete print
55,90 RON
Șosete broderie Sponge Bob
39,90 RON
Set 3 perechi șosete scurte broderie
39,90 RON
```

Selenium [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) is quite good.

Comment: Thank you so much! So the problem was that the page was being loaded dynamically as I scroll and the class names didnt match?

Comment: One problem was the dynamics of page load (so you only got 20 products), second (and third etc) problem was the way you defined the range. Also, those long XPATHs look fragile enough - not the proper way of locating an element. Also, you need a dot in front of XPATH expression when searching inside an element, otherwise the search is performed for the whole page. Quite a few issues there.

Comment: why are footer and pbody important?

Comment: Footer is not important - I was testing if I can scroll directly to footer - but page will not load all items. Page body is important because we send the PAGE_DOWN key to it, so we can scroll incrementally.